# AttributeError: 'QgsComposition' object has no attribute 'setMapCanvas'

Tags: python, pyqt, qgis

I am trying to save map and its legends using QGis Map composer. I have already template .

Here is code in python.

```
layers =iface.legendInterface().layers()
canvas=iface.mapCanvas()

for layer in layers:
# myFile = r"C:\Users\craj\Downloads\GraduatedTheme.qpt"
    myFile = r"C:\Users\craj\Downloads\GraduatedTheme.qpt"
    myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
    myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
    myTemplateFile.close()
    myDocument = QDomDocument()
    myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent, False)
    newcomp = iface.createNewComposer()
    newcomp.composition().loadFromTemplate(myDocument)
    newcomp.composition().refreshItems()
    for a in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
        iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(a, False)
    iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, True)
    newcomp.composition().refreshItems()
    map_item = newcomp.composition()
    map_item.getComposerItemById('map')
    map_item.setMapCanvas(canvas)
    map_item.zoomToExtent(canvas.extent())
    newcomp.composition().refreshItems()
    legend_item = newcomp.composition().getComposerItemById('legend')
    legend_item.updateLegend()
    newcomp.composition().refreshItems()
    imagePath ='C:/Users/craj/Downloads/'+layer.name()+'.png'
    image = newcomp.composition().printPageAsRaster(0)
    image.save(imagePath,'png')
```

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

```
AttributeError: 'QgsComposition' object has no attribute 'setMapCanvas' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/craj/.qgis2/python/plugins\JoinAttribute\Join_Attribute.py", line 436, in run
map_item.setMapCanvas(canvas)
AttributeError: 'QgsComposition' object has no attribute 'setMapCanvas'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [docs](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsComposition.html) there is no `setMapCanvas` on `QgsComposition`. This method is in several other classes, such as [`QgsComposerMap`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsComposerMap.html). So based on the code calling `getComposerItemById()` what you likely need is this:

```
composition = newcomp.composition()
map_item = composition.getComposerItemById('map')
map_item.setMapCanvas(canvas)
```

Comment: Thanks  for answer. But after changes I got another error:       

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setMapCanvas' Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/craj/.qgis2/python/plugins\JoinAttribute\Join_Attr‌​‌​ibute.py", line 437, in run map_item.setMapCanvas(canvas) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setMapCanvas' –